# Best practise for rendering views pulled via AJAX in to existing DOM tree

Tags: html, ajax, client-side

I imagine this is a common scenario:

You have a list of items in a page, for (a trivial) example:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

A button exists that allows you to load in 3 more items via AJAX — the 'easy' way to do this is to just return the HTML of the 3 new items and then inject them in to the DOM.

However, if we wish to do some client-side manipulation of this data, we then have to parse the returned HTML, manipulate the data and then re-template it and then inject in to DOM.

I would imagine, for less trivial applications, the server would return the data in JSON format ready to be manipulated and then templated. However, you have redundancy now with your 'template' existing both server-side and in your client-side logic. Furthermore, if you are using something like Backbone to handle the view/model and maybe Mustache or something for the templating it becomes more complicated.

How do we handle this redundancy? Have the server return a template, too?

Comment: I dont think if we create a mustache template, it will add redundancy. You will have just one template in the views which will generate `li` with the JSON provided.

Comment: ok, let's say that template is reasonably complex — if it changes you have to update both your server-side code and your client-side.

Comment: @dr_tchock it seems you want to use best practices in a "non-best-practiced" development. Depending on the time you got, you should choose whether to implement redundancy or the template mentioned by Ishank Gupta. 
Next time, try to implement non-dependant server-side/client-side (for example using [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)).

Comment: I'm just interested in how other people handle what I should imagine is a very common scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to keep all data processing and rendering on the server, due not just to redundancy, but to separation of concerns. If you want to render against different data or a different template, then send a modified request which returns HTML that you can directly insert without having to munge it.

Comment: So just return the HTML?

Comment: Yes, i.e., return HTML from the server that you can just append directly without having to munge it first.

Comment: I realise this is a probably a fairly subjective question anyway and I believe this is the most useful answer — I hadn't thought about modifying the request and keeping all the logic server-side.

Answer (score 0):

An approach, could be to generate the js dinamically (on server-side): generating a var containing the first 3 elements formatted as json, then call the function which add the `li`s on load.

This way, you will avoid redundancy and create client-side manipulation.

Comment: I have seen this approach — not sure I like it although it does solve the problem. Would be interested if it is common practise.